# Failed to send out e-mail using email plugin at Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

[image: Defined the Email notification plugin configuration]

Configured right email and password but still getting following Error :

```
com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPSendFailedException: 530-5.5.1 Authentication Required. Learn more at
```

530 5.5.1  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError u16sm2613119pjb.2 - gsmtp

```
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.issueSendCommand(SMTPTransport.java:2057)
at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.mailFrom(SMTPTransport.java:1580)
```